# Windows 7 update KB4523206 fails with the error 80242016

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Windows 7 update [KB4523206](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4523206/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-server-2008-r2-sp1) fails with the error code 80242016. According to [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/help-with-recent-update-for-windows-7-for-x64/b4296392-f901-46ab-937a-b40142964eb6) some others have the same problem. However, no solution has been provided at the moment. How can I install the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from an old page at  Answers.Microsoft  (2009)

Windows Update error code 0x80242016 = WU_E_UH_POSTREBOOTUNEXPECTEDSTATE
The state of the update after its post-reboot operation has completed is unexpected.

(ie., Some software can be stopping the update before the machine is being rebooting, not allowing it to complete properly.)

PostRebootUnexpectedSTATE

I suggest you check for malware / virus's, etc., stop or 
uninstall any 3rd party firewalls.

Create a shortcut on your desktop using the system Cleanup Manager:

%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe

Right-click the Icon and choose Run As Adminstrator and choose (C:)
Let it run through the process and it should give you an options box
Check the boxs

[x] Service Pack and Backup Files
[x] Windows Update Cleanup <-- You might not find this listed

If you have never run Cleanup before it will probably take a while to finish...

Then try running the "Deployment Image Servicing and Management".

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Enter your Temp folder (both in User.... and 
Windows\Temp and remove older files 
(older than a week, maybe even older than two days).

REBOOT.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! We had yesterday one optional update and received today two new updates (1 required, 1 optional). After installing them and running Cleanup Manager as suggested above the update KB4523206 installed successfully.

Comment: That's great, happy it worked out for you. You now might want to defrag your hard disk(s).